# How do I prevent the use of arbitrary methods, for example String.lastIndexOf()

Tags: java, classloader

I have a scenario where I want to run code that I don't control. I want to prevent arbitrary standard JDK methods from being used in that code (for example, I want to prevent the usage of the lastIndexOf() method on any String objects).

If a forbidden method is used, it should result in a run time exception.

I suspect this might be possible with a custom class loader but I'm not sure how to approach this. Part of the problem I ran into is that String is a final class that can't be extended.

Example:

```
//I control this code
int result = SomeClass.method("foo") //I don't control SomeClass

//A valid implementation of SomeClass.method()
int method(String in) {return 1;}

//An invalid implementation of SomeClass.method()
int method(String in) {return in.lastIndexOf("o");}
//the above should throw an error at run time when called from my code
```

Comment: You could mock every class with `PowerMockito` and throw exceptions when a bad method is called, but that seems somewhat unconvenient

Comment: have a look at AspectJ - is has the ability to add `aspects` to any class/method

Comment: I'd prefer static code analysis to detect "illegal method" uses. Your proposed approach will incur runtime overhead. Testing might miss an illegal use.

Comment: @leftbit Runtime overhead is not a concern. Also, I'm not facing a sophisticated "adversary" :) This will be used in the context of an "automatic marking" program for students.

Comment: IMHO this is an XY problem... It will be extremely hard to achieve and there will probably be ways to work around any limitation you put. Basically you want a sandbox, and they are extremely hard to implement properly and are routinuely broken. Also in your example: it's extremely easy to reimplement lastIndexOf with a loop, so what do you achieve? Is this for teaching programming and hence you don't want the users to cheat? Maybe just using reflection and making the methods private might work in that case.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Yes, exactly. They should implement their own lastIndexOf if needed. I'll take a look at the reflection option, setting them to private.

Comment: I think for teaching, hiding methods is the wrong approach. But you could, for example, fail a test (such as an [archunit-test](https://www.archunit.org/getting-started)) if certain forbidden methods are used.

Comment: Would a [security manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) help?

Comment: Given that almost all Java library methods, including `String.lastIndexOf()`, can be implemented in pure Java without delegating to other Java library methods, doing this would be entirely pointless. Doubly so when you consider that open source implementations are available, so the restriction could be circumvented for almost no effort.

Comment: Given this is an XY Problem, it is unclear what the **real** problem here is.

Comment: @Raedwald Please just read the question. I don't care if the method is re-implemented in pure Java, in fact that is the intention. I only specifically care about preventing the use of some known method in a known class. I don't understand the point of invoking, "this is an XY problem". Either the specific thing I'm asking about is possible or it isn't - and if it isn't, then an explanation why would be an acceptable answer. Don't worry about the "real" problem, I already have a workaround for that. But in the hopes of learning something, I want to know if what I ask in my question can be done.

Comment: "If a forbidden method is used, it should result in a run time exception." - Is that a hard requirement? For example, wouldn't it be fine to just inspect the class files beforehand and reject the program without even running it? I'd expect that to be fine for the purpose of an automatic marking program. This is why it's important to understand the context.

Comment: @JonSkeet In terms of solving the root problem, in the end I just replaced the question with another one that doesn't have requirements about forbidden methods. A runtime exception would be the most convenient for the way the automatic marking is currently done (i.e. least changes to the system) and I wanted to know if this was possible. Those two things are why I was not interested in alternative solutions. In retrospect, it was probably frustrating that I was being cagey about the context, so I apologize for that - my intention was to try keep the question focused on my particular objective.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested Reflection as a solution but what you want is an approach to tackle your problem and not a technical solution for it.

The domain of your problem can be much bigger than what we are discussing here.

Comment: You cannot inspect method body with reflection

Answer (score 0):

I remember writing a custom findbugs detector that looked for specific method calls. In my case it analysed it's parameters as well, but it looks your case is a bit simpler.

Alternatively, you can use ASM library.

Most naively, you can disassemble the class with javap and grep the output.

Comment: The ASM library looks promising, I'll have a further look into that.

Comment: I don't see how you could do intercept a method call disassembling it and then searching with grep.

Comment: @fidudidu If you read through the comments under question, the author wants to automate grading of students tasks, and he wants to prohibit some methods from the solution. If I understand correctly, it is not required to perform this check in runtime. Any kind of analysis of students code is allowed.

Comment: @Lesiak I was understanding the problem as if it was a run-time verification operation but indeed you are correct as nothing is said about it. Regarding your 
proposed solution it solves part of the problem: what if a student invokes that String method using reflection? it won't be trivial to find it with a grep operation.

Comment: @fidudidu I think you are right, an adversary (if you call a student an adversary) can easily bypass any of the methods proposed by me. Reflection or copying an implementation from OpenJdk cannot be noticed with methods proposed by me.